# Can't update grub to work in dual boot with Windows 10 & Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I bought a laptop Lenovo IdeaPad S145 which came pre-installed with Windows 10. Then I prepared an Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS bootable usb drive and installed Ubuntu alongside Windows 10. 
To make it happen I had to modify "Boot mode" to "Legacy support". Now if I have to boot Windows then "Boot mode" should be "UEFI" and for Ubuntu "Legacy mode". I tried fixing it using boot-repair but boot repair already shows "separate /boot/efi/ partition" and selected the efi partition present on SSD. 
I have created summary using boot-repair
http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/hp7nGk3xjQ/
Please suggest me how can I enable a dual boot in grub menu.

Comment: Reinstall Ubuntu in UEFI mode.

Comment: Go into BIOS and change to UEFI mode not Legacy. Also disable Secure Boot. Win10 is installed on an M.2 GPT formatted disk which must boot in UEFI mode. Boot to Live Ubuntu, remove partition nvme0n1p5 using Gparted, try another boot-repair then reboot.

Comment: @PaulBenson, [This](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UEFI/SecureBoot) article (as well as my experience) actually states that `Ubuntu` supports `secure boot` completely

Comment: Did you try using the .exe installer which comes in the ISO file?

Comment: @d4rk4ng31 I'm well aware Ubuntu supports Secure Boot. The problem is when you're trying to set up a dual boot with Win10 while SB is enabled, once completed with some machines they boot straight into Win10. That happened to me in the beginning.

Comment: @PaulBenson, Umm.. yeah, you need to go into boot options using F9 (or equivalent on your machine and select Linux). I still need to do that, as I do not have a boot-loader installed for Linux

Comment: @d4rk4ng31 Absurd idea. Most  sensible Ubuntu users prefer to use grub rather than have to rely each time on tapping F9 whatever at start-up, to bring up the BIOS menu to choose a system. That's the whole point of having a grub menu/boot manager.

Comment: @PaulBenson, so is seeing the grub page and needing to press a key even when you want to go to the default OS of your choice. ;) (Or waiting for 3 extra seconds, when you need not)

Comment: @All Thanks for the comments. Apologies for the delay as wifi drivers of wifi adapter wasn't automatically installed and required some more googling. I already did a reinstallation of ubuntu with UEFI mode ON. During my previous installation, I wasn't aware of the differences between UEFI & legacy mode and wasted a lot of time fixing the grub menu.

Answer (score 1):

I have had this problem with certain laptops. My usual solution is.

Set boot mode to UEFI. Plug in the Ubuntu install/live usb drive.
Don't boot, go into boot order menu. There should be an entry for OEM manufacturer install or something similarly named. Go into that and follow installation instructions.Take care of the extra partitions u need to create here, from the usual Ubuntu install.

This solution has usually worked for me and is a quick fix.(Do explore other options if you have the time)

hope it helps you today.